# Adding event handlers to specific classname in iframe in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, mouseevent

I'm integrating a 3rd party iframe into my website in react. Is there a way to add onClick event handler to specific classname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser’s security model won’t allow this unless the iframe is rendering content from the same domain the page is served from.